# How to send data from a tokio TcpStream using actix-web HttpResponse

Tags: tcp, rust, stream, rust-tokio, actix-web

I have a [TcpStream](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.2.11/tokio/net/struct.TcpStream.html) from which I need to read `N` bytes and send them as [HttpResponse](https://docs.rs/actix-web/2.0.0/actix_web/struct.HttpResponse.html) (I will still need to use the stream later on). At the moment I'm using the following code:

```rust
use futures::channel::mpsc;
use actix_web::HttpResponse;
use tokio::net::TcpStream;

let stream: TcpStream = ...;
let mut stream = stream.take(N);
let (mut sender, receiver) = mpsc::unbounded();

loop {
    let mut buffer = vec![0; BUFF_SIZE];
    let n = stream.read(&mut buffer).await?;
    if n > 0 {
        buffer.truncate(n);
        let data = Ok(web::Bytes::from(buffer));
        sender.send(data).await?;
    } else {
        break;
    }
}

// do more stuff with the TCP stream
let mut stream = stream.into_inner();
...


Ok(HttpResponse::Ok().streaming(receiver))
```

It works, but I'd like to know if it could be improved, as I couldn't find a better solution that wouldn't require the use of the `mpsc::channel` as well as the need to allocate a new `buffer` and `web::Bytes` for every read (besides the fact that I need to specify an arbitrary `BUFF_SIZE`).